# How do I reinitialize a singleton that I don't have full control over in the middle of an app?

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, singleton

I have a compiled external library that I'm using in my (Objective-C++) code. This library has a singleton class to store some information throughout the duration of the application being used. I really need a way to be able to remove the loaded information and reload it in the middle of the application. Or to reload the application so that this singleton is reinitialised.

In the header files there is no way to reset the class information.

The way I get an instance of it is:

```
Singleton::getInstance();
```

In the header file this is shown as:

```
static Singleton& getInstance();
```

I would like a way to be able to delete this instance and reinitialise another instance.

Is there any way to do this? This singleton is only being used on one (the main) thread.

### Extra information

When the application first loads I have to call:

```
Singleton::getInstance().load();
```

so that it loads information from the Documents directory of the app and create an internal structure. I replace those files in the Documents directory in the middle of the application running and I want it to reinitialise. If I call the above function again I get an error because the person who wrote this library doesn't allow the load function to be called twice.

I tried some stuff like:

```
delete &Singleton::getInstance();
```

but I don't know how I should reinitialise it afterwards. As calling

```
Singleton::getInstance();
```

crashes the app.

Comment: You'd have to find a flaw in the design of that `Singleton` class, a flaw that makes that singleton not a strict one. Maybe try subclassing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the API is providing you a way to do it, it's probably impossible.

But I would have try to rerun the "load" function after I call the delete...

Comment: Thanks, the problem is when I delete it and try to call `Singleton::getInstance();` I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message.

Comment: After the "delete" you can't call "getInstance", that's for sure cause the object is probably deleted. But calling "Load" may create a new instance and then the "getInstance" may work. If that doesn't work and the API doesn't provide a way to clean the information then it's just a bad programming of who wrote the original lib.

Comment: It probably means that calling `getInstance()` for the second time, throws an exception. And that's done on purpose by the author of your singleton, I believe.

Comment: @Roee: correct singleton design is not "a bad programming" ;)

Comment: @delirus: If your user need to restart the data, and since it's a singleton he can't create a new instance. You should at list provide an API to restart it. otherwise (In my opinion) it's a bad programming...

Comment: @Roee: I agree, it depends on intended lib features. In my framework I deliberately don't allow to reinitialize my singleton instance.

Comment: The only load function is `Singleton::getInstance().load();` which is what reads files from the file system, so that will still give an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after delete is called. Other than that it's only `Singleton::getInstance()` that I assume is initialising the class. Do you guys know of any way to reset the state of that class or the static library? I'm quite new to C++.

Comment: Tayeb: For short, it's the choice of the one who made the lib. if he didn't want to have this option then you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks. In my application I'm calling load then checking online if there's any updated data, if there is: call load again. The way I'll solve it is by making the user wait a little longer at load time while the app is checking online for new data before calling load, as I only have one shot at loading the data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the Singleton from within a dinamic link library, instead of from within your own application. If you need to reinstantiate, unload the dll (or .so depending on the OS you are running on) module and reload it.

Not sure if this works though, but I guess it is worth a try.

Later edit: just noticed the iOS tag. Don't know if iOS has dynamic loadable modules, so my answer may not apply.

Comment: Thanks, it's a static library so I won't be able to unload it and reload it. Although something like that would help, where I can restore the state of everything in that library.

Comment: I saw it is a static library, you can make a dynamic one that links to the static, then load that. Maybe that would do the trick.